# Generate .tab file Azure Data Factory with specific static text up to 4 rows

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In my .tab file, I need to have first 4 line some static text. 5 th row should be kept empty.The sql data(data to copy)  should be added from line 6 onwards. Any leads for this?

Comment: can you provide what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am working on a pipeline to create a .tab file froma table in sql. During cretaion this .tab file should have first 4 line with static row. I am doing some research work on how to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the requirement you mentioned is not directly possible in ADF to pass 4 lines static text then skip one line and then copy sql dataset.

- To achieve your scenario, you have to first create a text file with 4 lines of static text and 1 empty line as below.
  [image]

**Get a SQL table and save results as TAB file:**

- Create a SQL Dataset with table table:
  [image]
- Create another Dataset for the file with static text. I'm using ADLS in this example, but the concept is the same for other storage types:
  [image]
- Create another Dataset for the TAB file. I'm using ADLS in this example, but the concept is the same for other storage types:
  [image]

**Type 1 (all the columns with tab separated)**

- In your pipeline, add a DataFlow activity. create new dataflow, select source1 as, Dataset created for the file with static text.
  [image]
- Then in your dataflow activity create another source as SQL db dataset which you created earlier
  [image]
- Then after source 1 take union transformation to combine both the dataset.
  [image]
- Then store the output to destination tabfile sink settings as below.
  [image]

***Output:***

[image]

**Type 2 (combine all the columns as tab separated string)**

- In your pipeline, add a DataFlow activity. create new dataflow, select source1 as, Dataset created for the file with static text.
  [image]
- Then in your dataflow activity create another source as SQL db dataset which you created earlier
  [image]
- Then create derived column for source 2 and concat all columns with tab separation `concatWS(' ',col1,col2,col3,col4)`
  [image]
  [image]
- After this take select transformation and delete columns which are not required
  [image]
- Then after source 1 take union transformation to combine source1 data with select column data.
  [image]
- Then store the output to destination tabfile sink settings as below.
  [image]

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: I tried with Type 2. After creating the file, i mean output  file when dowloaded , type is showing as File, not as tab.  In the filename option for sink, do we need to add anything?

Comment: you can simply pass file name as `filename.tab`  in output to singe file of sink setting. or you can pass this expression `concat('filename','.tab')`

Comment: Yes. I have done  that . So now tab file is generated. Thanks Pratik